# How to stop django to store images path in sqlite3 database

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Following code work fine to store thumbnails images in  /media/ directory. i want to store all images in following directory but django also save images path in database. Please let me know, how i can stop django to save their path and address in database ?

**model.py : Code**

```
from django.db import models
    class Document(models.Model):
        thumbnail = models.ImageField()
```

**views.py : Code**

```
from .models import Document
from .forms import DocumentForm

    if (request.FILES['thumbnail']):
        newdoc = Document(thumbnail = request.FILES['thumbnail'])
        newdoc.save()
```

**forms.py : Code**

```
from django import forms

    class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
        thumbnail = forms.ImageField(
        label='Select a file',
        help_text='max. 42 megabytes'
        )
```

**template.html : Code**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="imgUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.thumbnail.label_tag }} {{ form.thumbnail.help_text }}</p>
    <p>
        {{ form.thumbnail.errors }}
        {{ form.thumbnail }}
        <button type="submit" id="thumbUpload" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Upload Thumbnails</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to override your form method , before save your validform , or you can handle with your code , you don't need to have model or form you can handle with

```
image = request.FILES['myfile']
```

now you have your image you can save it directly without model

example reproduced from Django Documentation.

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    destination = open('file path', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

you can change 'file path ' with your path where you want to store your image

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about what you are trying to achieve but the solution is barely simple. Just get the file object and save...

oh.. one more thing just remove all the thumbnail in models.py and other files...

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    destination = open('your_media_path/media/file.png', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

in your POST view

```
f = request.FILES['thumbnail']
handle_uploaded_file(f)
```